# Android ListView Text Color white

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom `listview` by using an `adapter` which has alternate background color.
The problem is that the text which are strings (over 100+ of strings) are set to the color of `Color.BLACK` but in the `listview` the first couple of strings are white and then the rest are black.

```
@Override  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);  
    TextView tv = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    int colorPos = position % color.length; 
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    view.setBackgroundColor(color[colorPos]);  
    return view;  
}
```

I can't detect the problem why the first are white then the others are black, is it something to with loading or something? because my text (the strings) they are over 100.

**UPDATE**

This is the listView code:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    Strings.Advices);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

And the strings:

```
public class Strings {
    public static String Advices[] = {
       "advice",
       "advice",
       "adc",
       "add",
    };
}
```

Comment: Where is your listview code and array? I need to see that.

Comment: Why are you calling `getView` twice? Why do you assume `getView` will give you a valid view?

Comment: @K-ballo Didn't understand what you mean :/

Comment: Didn't the answer that Sam posted resolve your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TextView does nothing. Typically you need to use `findViewById()` to locate the TextView in your row's layout. Since you are using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which is a TextView itself, we can skip that step:

```
@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);  
    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
    int colorPos = position % color.length; 
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    view.setBackgroundColor(color[colorPos]);  
    return view;  
}
```

But the `getView()` method of any built-in Adapter is very generic, therefor slow... You should write your own to take full advantage of the Adapter's recycler and the ViewHolder concept. Please watch this Google Talk [Turbo Charge Your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) (and/or the [World of ListView](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)) to help you write an efficient adapter.

> The problem is that the text which are strings ( over 100+ of strings ) are set to the color of Color.BLACK but in the listview the first couple of strings are white and then the rest are black

I assume that this change happens when you scroll the ListView, this is *directly* linked to how the View recycler behaves.

Comment: Sorry but how do I use findViewById() when strings have no id ?

Comment: When i scroll the listview the strings become black as I wanted Color.BLACK

Comment: Ok, I noticed that your are using `simple_list_item_1.xml` which is just a TextView, so we can just cast the View to a TextView. (Otherwise you can use the id `android.R.id.text1`.) I updated my answer.

Comment: making it " TextView tv = (TextView) view;
" solved my problem, thanks =) I didn't think of that, I used (view) :P

Comment: Glad I could help. You should watch the videos, they have _so_ much good information. Also consider using your own XML layout if you only want to change the text and background color instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. :)

Comment: I downloaded the pdf presentations of what you gave me, maybe ill watch the videos later. Okay, ill take your advice. thank you.